# What is the correct way of using '*' keyword in a cucumber feature file

Tags: cucumber, gherkin

I have multiple validations to be done on some web UI. So instead of writing

```
Then I see "foo" element on the page
And I want the user to see "bar" text
.
.
.
And new order is generated
```

I want my feature file to be more readable(this might go app-specific and not business specific) and should go something like this

```
Then following validations are made
     * "foo" element is visible
     * "bar" text is visible
     .
     .
     .
     * new order is generated
```

My Questions is, '*' keyword has the ability to adapt to any step according to documentation, am I using it correctly? ( I think not because my IDE doesn't think so). What is the correct way of using it?
In other words, how to write steps with * so that IDE understands and recognizes step definition

Let me know if I am not understanding this correctly.

EDIT:
The way I am using '*' is correct, we have to write something like

```
* "foo" is present
```

IDE doesn't recognize it may be a problem with the plugin, I wrote the step and the corresponding step definition with any of the standard keywords (Given/When/Then), cucumber recognizes it and works accordingly

Comment: You can use scenario outline to.pass web element value n validate that

Comment: Using a scenario outline is here is a really bad idea. It will create a new scenario for each validation, vastly increasing runtime

Answer (score 1):

The approach I'd use is to find the overall name for all the validations, what are your validations validating?

When you have done that write a single step

`Then 'my foo should be valid'`

then implement this as something like

`Then 'my foo should be valid' do
  should_have_valid_bar
  should_have_valid_baz
  ...
end`

and then write the helper methods to make this work. This will do the following

1. Simplify your feature file and make it much easier to read.
2. Make it much cheaper to add or modify validations.
3. Transfer responsibility to the programmer.
4. Simplify your step definitions and reduce their number

In general keep you scnenarios simple and short and don't include detail about HOW things are done. Push that HOW down into step definitions and helper methods.

Comment: while this is an excellent suggestion, it doesn't answer my question. Maybe I mixed to things while asking the question. I want to achieve 2 things
1. Understand how * is used in step
2. Re-use each * marked step in another scenario
So writing the series of validation logic into step definitions sounds great, but I won't be able to reuse the individual validation. Makes sense?

Comment: where do you get this idea that you can * as a keyword? Are you trying to create steps that can be both Given When's and Then's?

Comment: "Are you trying to create steps that can be both Given When's and Then's", in a way, Yes. Designed the tests to achieve a high level of reusability and granularity. As I already mentioned, this might not look very business case friendly but considering the application, serves the purpose best.

Comment: In Cucumber Given When and Then are synonymous. There are plenty of good reasons why you should not use the same step with different keywords, but there is nothing stopping you from doing this. So if you have implemented `Given I login` you can use that step with `When I login` and `Then I login`.

Answer (score 0):

The GWT should be seen as following:
   Given some sort of pre-condition, something kind of setup for the test.
   When the action that happens
   Then The expected result of the action

the And and But are just representations of the preceding Given, When or Then.

Sometimes, a scenario in this way just is not the best approach (not all jobs need the same tool) and a list of "stuff" is more desirable. i.e.

```
* Open web browser
* Go to google
* Search for Cheese
* Select a cheese to buy
* go to shop
* buy cheese
* eat cheese
* feel happy
```

This is where the * should be used to show a list that is a order of instructions. (I'd also be happy to argue that the above could quite easily be written into GWT and that most things can if you understand what you are trying to describe well enough).